# What is the algorithm to output the list of swaps in the Steinhaus–Johnson–Trotter algorithm for permutations?

Tags: math, permutation

According to [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinhaus%E2%80%93Johnson%E2%80%93Trotter_algorithm), it's possible to output a list of permutation where each new permutation is only a single, adjacent swap different from the previous permutation.  And this is exhaustive, it goes through all the permutations.

I'm having difficulty understanding the algorithm from the description.  I want to write an algorithm to output the swaps needed between each permutation.

Comment: Every time a swap is done, just output it as well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As deciding the next element that needs swapping is defined by the current state of the permutation, generating the next swap isn't any easier than generating the next permutation.

If I had to generate either, I'd aim for an implementation of [Even's speedup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinhaus%E2%80%93Johnson%E2%80%93Trotter_algorithm#Even.27s_speedup). The algorithm described there should be fairly easy to translate into most programming languages. You can then output the permutations and mark the swaps as well if you whish to. The following Python code will do just that:

```python
class Elt(object):
    def __init__(self, dir, name):
        self.dir = dir
        self.name = name

n = 6
p = [Elt(0 if i == 0 else -1, i + 1) for i in range(n)]
while(True):
    print(' '.join(str(i.name) for i in p))
    oldpos = None
    for i in range(n):
        if p[i].dir != 0 and (oldpos is None or p[oldpos].name < p[i].name):
            oldpos = i
    if oldpos is None:
        break
    mover = p[oldpos]
    newpos = oldpos + mover.dir
    p[oldpos] = p[newpos]
    p[newpos] = mover
    print(' '*(oldpos + newpos) + 'X')
    if mover.dir == -1 and (newpos == 0 or p[newpos - 1].name > mover.name):
        mover.dir = 0
    if mover.dir == 1 and (newpos == (n - 1) or p[newpos + 1].name > mover.name):
        mover.dir = 0
    for i in range(newpos):
        if p[i].name > mover.name:
            p[i].dir = 1
    for i in range(newpos, n):
        if p[i].name > mover.name:
            p[i].dir = -1
```

Comment: Looks good!  I assume that you tested it?  I don't have a python compiler handy.  I wish that there were a way to do without those for loops.  Is there an algorithm that does single swaps, possibly not adjacent, but runs faster?

Comment: Python is interpreted, not compiled. You can also [execute it online](http://codepad.org/c0zHJs2e). How to iterate over permutations very much depends on language; some languages or libraries provide tools for this. E.g. in C++ you could use [`next_permutation`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/next_permutation.html) to iterate over the permutations. If your licensing allows, you can see how the GNU gcc libstdc++ implementation [implements this](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.1/libstdc++/api/a01462_source.html#l03679).

Comment: My last comment isn't an exact reply to your comment, I noticed: `next_permutation` iterates in lexicographical order, so subsequent permutations may differ by more than a single non-adjacent swap. Note that for the SJT algo, [Wikipedia states](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinhaus%E2%80%93Johnson%E2%80%93Trotter_algorithm#Even.27s_speedup) that “a more complex loopless version of the same procedure allows it to be performed in constant time per permutation in every case; however, the modifications needed to eliminate loops from the procedure make it slower in practice.”

Comment: That SJT assessment is from Sedgewick, 1977. How processors work have changed a lot in the meantime (instruction parallelism), so I'm not sure how much we can rely on the analysis still.